# Make JavaFX radiobutton event fire only once

Tags: javafx, radio-button, toggle

I have radiobuttons and event listener as on Oracle demo page.
It works, it saves data to db, but the problem is, it fires as many times as there are radios in group.
I would like it to be toggled only ONCE so I'd process the data only once.

Here's the relevant code (note I have many radio groups so I'm using maps):

```
private Map<Integer, RadioButton> Radios = new HashMap<>();
private Map<Integer, ToggleGroup> RadioGroups = new HashMap<>();

(...)
DrawRadio (int group, int id, String label) {

    if (RadioGroups.get(group) == null) {
        RadioGroups.put(group, new ToggleGroup());
    }

    (...)

    Radios.put(id, new RadioButton(label));
    Radios.get(id).setToggleGroup(RadioGroups.get(group));
    Radios.get(id).setUserData(ans_id);

    (...)

    RadioGroups.get(group).selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>(){
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ov, Toggle old_toggle, Toggle new_toggle) {

            if (RG.getSelectedToggle().equals(new_toggle)) {
                System.out.println ("Called with ov:" + ov + ", old_tgl:" + old_toggle.toString() + " and new_tgl: " + new_toggle.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the output when I change selected radio from a to b is:

```
Called with ov:ReadOnlyObjectProperty [value: RadioButton@3814fb6f[styleClass=radio-button]'b'], old_tgl:RadioButton@5b417598[styleClass=radio-button]'a' and new_tgl: RadioButton@3814fb6f[styleClass=radio-button]'b'
Called with ov:ReadOnlyObjectProperty [value: RadioButton@3814fb6f[styleClass=radio-button]'b'], old_tgl:RadioButton@5b417598[styleClass=radio-button]'a' and new_tgl: RadioButton@3814fb6f[styleClass=radio-button]'b'
Called with ov:ReadOnlyObjectProperty [value: RadioButton@3814fb6f[styleClass=radio-button]'b'], old_tgl:RadioButton@5b417598[styleClass=radio-button]'a' and new_tgl: RadioButton@3814fb6f[styleClass=radio-button]'b'
Called with ov:ReadOnlyObjectProperty [value: RadioButton@3814fb6f[styleClass=radio-button]'b'], old_tgl:RadioButton@5b417598[styleClass=radio-button]'a' and new_tgl: RadioButton@3814fb6f[styleClass=radio-button]'b'
Called with ov:ReadOnlyObjectProperty [value: RadioButton@3814fb6f[styleClass=radio-button]'b'], old_tgl:RadioButton@5b417598[styleClass=radio-button]'a' and new_tgl: RadioButton@3814fb6f[styleClass=radio-button]'b'
```

I'd like it only to be **once**, so:

```
Called with ov:ReadOnlyObjectProperty [value: RadioButton@3814fb6f[styleClass=radio-button]'b'], old_tgl:RadioButton@5b417598[styleClass=radio-button]'a' and new_tgl: RadioButton@3814fb6f[styleClass=radio-button]'b'
```

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue, but couldn't. I would like to see what you are doing in your code. Can you create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this ?

Comment: Debug your `RadioGroups.get(group)...` code. You may be adding the same listener to that same property more than once.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem - everytime I called DrawRadio I added event listener!

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed. As I said before, the problem was as Uluk pointed out- everytime I called the function, I created event listener.

The fix is to add check if the RadioGroup is generated (for the first time):

```
DrawRadio (int group, int id, String label) {

    boolean AddListener = false;

    if (RadioGroups.get(group) == null) {
        AddListener = true;
        RadioGroups.put(group, new ToggleGroup());
    }

    (...)
    if (AddListener == true) {
        RadioGroups.get(group).selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>(){
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> ov, Toggle old_toggle, Toggle new_toggle) {

                if (RG.getSelectedToggle().equals(new_toggle)) {
                    System.out.println ("Called with ov:" + ov + ", old_tgl:" + old_toggle.toString() + " and new_tgl: " + new_toggle.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```